# About Data safety section in Play store?

Tags: google-play-store, security, privacy

In the "Data safety" section of apps in Play Store, when it shows

> Data collected: photos and videos

or

> Data shared: photos and videos.

What does it mean? Or if some apps do not show it, does it mean no data is collected or shared?

Comment: Sorry your question is hard to understand without an example. Could you please pick an example app, link it in your question and best make a screen shot of the data safety section and include it in your question, too.

Comment: You might be interested in reading the official documentation [Provide information for Google Play's Data safety section](https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/10787469).